# Install HDF5 and H5PY in python under Linux 2.6

Tags: python, linux

I cannot figure out how to install hdf5-1.8.9-linux-x86_64-shared so that I can install h5py-2.0.1

I have extracted the "tar-balls" but cant find the setup.py file to run.

Has anyone else done this recently?

I'm running the shell through SSH, and I dont have root access so I need to install in my home folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have downloaded a binary.
For source installation :

http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/release_docs/INSTALL

Then for the python wrapper :

http://h5py.alfven.org/docs/intro/build.html

Comment: I downloaded hdf5 source, then ran ./configure and make install, seemed to work. Then ran setup.py in h5py... think it worked, thanks